# Should this question about the differences between two technologies really have been closed?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, reopen-closed

[A recent question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20876972/drools-fusion-vs-drools-expert) was put on hold by a moderator because it *appears* to violate one of the rules, quote: "too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long". Since I *know* the topic of the question very well, I'm sure that it can indeed be answered in as many lines I'm using here to put my question. (And there is only one possible answer.)

So, what can I do to alert the moderator that his decision may only be formally correct?

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/

Comment: I'm not so sure it can be answered to the satisfaction of the OP. They already disbelieve what they have uncovered by minimal research. If your answer relates to what can only be uncovered by substantial research, then fair enough. If it is a question which will be faced by many even after minimal research, then fair enough. If it is just to satisfy a Doubting Thomas, then I'd say the Close was fine.

Comment: @Bill Woodger : The confusion arises from some marketing hype with the intent of loudly announcing something which is just a handful of additional features - important enough, to be sure. OPs not the only one not seeing through the smokescreen - I've been watching this area for years.

Comment: @Mysticial : Having learned a lot and continuing to do so, I do know that the percentage of what I don't know as to what I know is getting smaller all the time. (So I think that I qualify for neither G. nor S. ;-) But the issue here isn't who knows more, it's about how one can help when someone else lets the shutters down.

Comment: I'd suggest you ask the OP to improve, so that you know the question is a genuine, substantial one worthy of a good Answer. If nothing happens, construct your own good Question, and Self Answer.

Comment: @Mysticial As Jeff eventually concludes at the end of the post you've linked to, an "X vs Y" question can be perfectly valid as long as it's restricted to a small enough scope that it's meaningfully answerable. From what the OP here has claimed, that seems to apply in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With respect to the title of your question, the answer is that moderators are not subject-matter experts. Although they are expected to have experience with the site topic in general, they are, in the course of their duties, not expected to have any specific knowledge about the particulars of any one specific area or another.

In general, "X vs Y" are bad questions. If these are two very specific technologies, the question may be on-topic. I'm not sure of a good way to distinguish the small subset of ok questions from the very large subset of bad questions a priori, however.

Comment: @walwal933: The title was meant do be catchy, but the real question is the last sentence. Of course, moderators can't know everything, but there ought to be a reasonable way of telling them that in this case it isn't "business as usual". Is it a comment using @ + username? I've not seen this useful hint on stackoverflow. Blindness?

Comment: @laune So yes, that will work in theory to alert a moderator who closes a question. In practice, their inboxes are probably too full for them to see it. A flag is better, though note that it may be some time before it is acted on (and if it is possible to improve the question, do so first as that will increase the likelihood of reopening).

Comment: OK, accepting with thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr version: Not all questions asking for comparisons between two technologies should be closed. If the precise thing to be compared is well-specified enough, and the relevant differences few enough, that there exists a single answer which is succinct and objectively correct, then the question certainly deserves to stay open.**

I don't know the technologies, so I may be wrong. But from what I can see, this shouldn't have been closed.

The closure seems to have been, in part, a knee-jerk reaction to seeing "vs" in the title, which makes people think of [Gorilla vs. Shark](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/) questions, a problem discussed by Jeff Atwood years ago. However, that seems to be misguided here, because:

1. Gorilla vs Shark questions ask **which is better** out of two technologies, which is almost always both **subjective** and **context-dependent**, and so will attract answers that are woolly and **opinion-based** or which only really apply to one particular context that the answerer has assumed applies.
2. Gorilla vs Shark questions compare two **significantly different technologies**, such that there are **many possibly relevant differences**. Thus nobody can really answer exhaustively or authoritatively.

From what you've said, none of these concerns apply here. First, it's clear from the question that the asker isn't asking for a subjective comparison; he's asking for a full description of all the differences between these two products. As such, it's clearly not an *inherently* subjective question. This much, the moderator who closed the question could have seen.

What he *couldn't* possibly know, though, is how broad the question is. Normally, a question that asks what the differences between two technologies would require a book's worth of text to answer - particularly language comparisons, like the *Python v. Perl* example Jeff quotes in the Gorilla vs Shark post.

However, *from what you've said*, this question is a special case where this doesn't apply. It sounds like these are two closely-related versions of the same technology with only a handful of (objective, easily listable) differences in their feature set:

> Since I *know* the topic of the question very well, I'm sure that it can indeed be answered in as many lines I'm using here to put my question. (And there is only one possible answer.)

The mod who closed [isn't an active contributor in the Java tag](https://stackoverflow.com/users/237838/andrew-barber?tab=tags) and so almost certainly did not have had the knowledge that you do; he arguably made the right call based on the evidence he could see. But if everything you say is true, the question deserves to be reopened.

Of course, I'm not qualified to judge whether your claim that there's a single succinct and objective answer to this question is actually true. It might help if other Drools experts weighed in. If you really want to prove your point, the best way would be to put your money where your mouth is and post, here, that *one possible answer* that can be given *in as many lines [as your] question*. Delivering a succinct, comprehensive and objective answer to a question is probably the best way to prove that such a thing is not impossible.

Comment: Bad questions should be closed: `In drools docs and examples I found over the internet they claim Drools Fusion and Drools Expert are different but I am not sure they are same or different.` = "I have no clue (at least as evidenced by the question) whether what I have already read is correct or not, or whether I should have read something else. Can you read it for me, and tell me what I should think, even though I'll perhaps not genuinely know why as I don't know how to evaluate it?"

Comment: @Mark Amery: Here's the answer I'd have posted.

Comment: Fusion is a superset of Expert, adding some features based on a timestamp and, optionally, a duration attribute in facts, then called "event". Temporal operators ("after", "during", etc) let you reason about their order, including overlap, and there's an auto-delete for outdated events.

Comment: Seeing this took only 4 lines, I might have mentioned "streams" as named sources for event sequences and real-time vs. virtual clocks. But that's all, folks.